# Android expandable list view last row child color change

Tags: android

I am using an Expandable list view. In that, i need to change the text color of the last child. I tried by comparing the child position is equal to last row. Condition working text color also changing, but sometime other child color also changing. all row texts are unique. How to use make this child loading fast. I tried with custom listview holder. Then, it is fast. But, child text color not working

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
                List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;

        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(
                    this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,
                    childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView li_tv_Subjects = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.li_tv_Subjects);
            TextView li_tv_Grade = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.li_tv_Grade);



            setControlsStyle.SetExpandableListViewChild(li_tv_Subjects);
            setControlsStyle.SetExpandableListViewChild(li_tv_Grade);


            li_tv_Subjects.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER);

            li_tv_Subjects.setText(childText.split(";")[0]);
            li_tv_Grade.setText(childText.split(";")[1]);

            if (childPosition==(listDataChild.size()-1))
{
li_tv_Subjects.setTextColor(android.r.color.blue);
li_tv_Grade.setTextColor(android.r.color.blue);
}



            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(
                    this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
            setControlsStyle.SetExpandableListViewHeader(lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
            TextView lg_tv_arrow = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lg_tv_arrow);



            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("FA1");
        listDataHeader.add("FA2");
        listDataHeader.add("SA1");

        // Adding child data
        top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("English;A");
        top250.add("Tamil;A");
        top250.add("Maths;C");
        top250.add("Science;D");
        top250.add("Social;B");
        top250.add("Drawing;A");
        top250.add(getResources().getString(R.string.TotalPrecentage) + ";90");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), top250);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), top250);

    }
```